# How to add info to getJSON response

Tags: jquery, json

I am using jQuery to grab JSON data for a page I'm coding.   I need to add DT_RowId as a key and set it equal to the id.

Here's what I have:

```
var recalls = [];

$.getJSON('ajax_datatables_get_json.php?what=contact_recalls', function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(index) {
        recalls.push({DT_RowId: data[index].id});
    }); 

});

console.log(recalls);
```

Here's a sample of what my JSON looks like:

```
[{"reason":"Clean\/Check","id":"294","recall_date":"2016-04-14","appt_reason_id":"28","datetime":"2016-04-29 15:25:11"},{"reason":null,"id":"290","recall_date":"2016-04-13","appt_reason_id":null,"datetime":"2016-04-29 12:57:05"}]
```

I am trying to use .push, assuming that's correct.  Right now there is nothing showing up in the the console for the array.   It's empty.   The JSON page does load properly and I can see the response.

Basically I want to push the id back into each JSON as a separate field called DT_RowID so I would get something like this:

```
[{"reason":"Clean\/Check","id":"294","recall_date":"2016-04-14","appt_reason_id":"28","datetime":"2016-04-29 15:25:11", "DT_RowId": "294"},
 ... ...
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each(data, function(index, obj) {
   obj.DT_RowId = obj.id;
   recalls.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: When I do that I still get [] showing up in my console if use:  console.log(recalls) .  That confuses me because if I still check the server response from Chrome Developer tools, I can see the ajax page loading and the JSON response showing for that page.  So I know there's JSON data!

Comment: I just put this into a page (along with some minimal html) and loaded it:
`<script>
var data = [{"reason":"Clean\/Check","id":"294","recall_date":"2016-04-14","appt_reason_id":"28","datetime":"2016-04-29 15:25:11"},{"reason":null,"id":"290","recall_date":"2016-04-13","appt_reason_id":null,"datetime":"2016-04-29 12:57:05"}];
var recalls = [];
$.each(data, function(index, obj) {
   obj.DT_RowId = obj.id;
   recalls.push(obj);
}); 
console.log(recalls);
</script>`
It works fine - gives me an array of 2 objects just as expected.

Comment: So here's what I just noticed.  I used a different computer that is running a server and ran the same page.  The object shows in the console.  When I refresh the page or go back to it later, nothing is logged in the console.   Can that happen?  There the first time only.

Comment: Here's what I'm working on. I'm trying to set data = myjson received via ajax.      var data;
    
    $.getJSON("ajax_datatables_get_json.php?what=contact_recalls", function(json){
        data = json;
    }); 

    var recalls = []; 

    $.each(data, function(index, obj) { 
        obj.DT_RowId = obj.id; 
        recalls.push(obj); 
    });

    console.log(recalls);